# Pass String to PHP with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass a string from javascript to php and then in php i must have to insert it's value in a sql database.

However the string is not with the correct value. It sends the number `1` instead of the string `chrome` to `main.php`. The string i want to pass is `Chrome`.

Any help please!

Here's my code.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

if (isChrome) {

  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "main.php",
        data: { value: 'Chrome' },
        success: function(data) {
           alert(data);
        }
    });     
  };  
});
```

Comment: Where is your php code?

Comment: Where `isChrome` is declared?

Comment: The issues are probably `isChrome` isn't returning as true properly, or your PHP code isn't working.  Please post both, and try commenting out `isChrome` to see if it works without it.

Comment: Post ur PHP code as well. The ajax call is okay

Comment: As far i get it, his/her variable `value` is posting 1 instead of `chrome` to `main.php`.

Answer (score 0):

The insert statement returns 1 if success so you have to echo the value in order to alert it

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {

  if (isChrome) {

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "main.php",
    data: { value: 'Chrome' },
    success: function(data) {
       alert(data);
    }
     });     
   };
```

});

in your main.php

```
  <?php
       //insert in mySQL here 
       echo $_POST['value'];
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code, you are sending to main.php a variable named 'value' wich contains 'Chrome'.
Then, in main.php, you can request this with

```
$my_value = $_POST["value"];
```

Hope this help you!